# Http Put request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

I have a spring-boot application that the only thing it does is receive http requests.

This is my spring cotroller:

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private CallRecording callRecording;

    @PutMapping(path = "/cdrpostbox/callrecording/{hostedAccountId}/{mp3FileName}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> callRecording(@PathVariable("hostedAccountId") String hostedAccountId, @PathVariable("mp3FileName") String mp3FileName, MultipartFile file) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(callRecording.service(hostedAccountId, mp3FileName, file)).body(null);
    }

}
```

I'm using Postman to send the request. The request that my spring application receives **can't** be changed, because the code is not maintained by my team.

[request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Gq2.png)

[request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE0ZR.png)

I found quite a few questions in here about the similar problems, but not quite the same problem that I have to solve. I tried adding and removing **@RequestBody** , replacing **@RequestBody** with **@RequestParam**, I tried the **MultiValueMap**, but it keeps returning the same error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "x"
```

I can't even debug the code because it fails before it reaches the controller.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more investigation, I found the solution.

```
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private CallRecording callRecording;

    @PutMapping(path = "/cdrpostbox/callrecording/{hostedAccountId}/{mp3FileName:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> callRecording(@PathVariable("hostedAccountId") String hostedAccountId, @PathVariable("mp3FileName") String mp3FileName, @RequestBody byte[] requestBody) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(callRecording.service(hostedAccountId, mp3FileName, requestBody)).body(null);
    }
```

It was missing the `@EnableWebMvc`. I also changed the mapping `{mp3FileName:.+}` because it was truncating the end of the request, you can check the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated) .

Thanks @Selindek for the help

Answer (score 0):

The content-type in the header is urlencoded, but you send binary data.

--- edit

If you want to get the file as a MultipartFile, then send the file as a form-data from postman, set the name of the data to file and add `@RequestParam` to the file argument in your method.

Comment: I changed my request, I'm not sending the header now. I also changed my controller `@PutMapping(path = "/cdrpostbox/callrecording/{hostedAccountId}/{mp3FileName}")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> callRecording(@PathVariable("hostedAccountId") String hostedAccountId, @PathVariable("mp3FileName") String mp3FileName, MultipartFile requestBody) {` but now the requestBody is null. What would be the solution for this problem?

Comment: I also found this question that asks the same as me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000409/spring-rest-upload-file-as-binary

Comment: Your request is not a multipart-request now. Change the last argument to `@RequestBody byte[] requestBody`